# How to calculate probability in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, tidyverse, probability

Hi so I'm taking a stats class, and we were given a dataset "NHANES" that we filtered down to get adult smokers --> "NHANES_adult".

```
library(NHANES)
# create a NHANES dataset without duplicated IDs 
NHANES <-
  NHANES %>%
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) 

NHANES_adult <- NHANES %>%
  filter(Age >= 18) %>%  # only include individuals 18 or older
  filter(SmokeNow != 'NA')  # drop any observations with NA for SmokeNow
```

My prof asked the following:

1b. Now let's take a single sample of 100 individuals from the NHANES_adult dataframe, and compute the proportion of smokers, saving it to a variable called p_smokers.

```
set.seed(12345)  # PROVIDED CODE - this will cause it to create the same
                 # random sample each time

sample_size = 100 # size of each sample

p_smokers <- NHANES_adult %>%
  sample(sample_size) %>%  # take a sample from the data frame [I think this is okay]
  ____(____ = ____(____)) %>% # compute the probability of smoking [This is the point at which I'm struggling to understand what one-line function fits these blank parameters.
  ____()  # extract the variable from the data frame [I believe this is the mutate() function?]

p_smokers
```

Comment: The homework question says to calculate the proportion of smokers not the probability.

Comment: Yes but in the comments is says probability

Comment: I guess a more precise statement would be to say that the proportion of smokers is the MLE of the probability (parameter) for smoking assuming a binomial process (smoking = yes/no). A bit sloppy but ok. @SalmaAbdel-Raheem Do you know how to calculate the proportion? For example, imagine you have 2 smokers and 8 non-smokers. What is the proportion of smokers amongst your cohort?

Comment: Proportion would be 2/8 or 0.25. But I guess I'm unclear on how to do that using dplyr @MauritsEvers

Comment: @MauritsEvers this is the original format in which my prof had wanted us to "fill in the blanks" with the code ____(____ = ____(____)) %>% # compute the probability of smoking

Comment: @SalmaAbdel-Raheem No, the proportion would be 2/10 not 2/8! How is smoking encoded in your data?

Comment: Hello @SalmaAbdel-Raheem, have you tried pull() ? That extracts the value

Comment: @MauritsEvers oops, you're right it would be 0.2, sorry I've been frustrated with this problem for a little while now. Smoking data is binary (yes/no) in a column that's titled as "SmokeNow".

Comment: @Manu will try the pull() function!

Comment: @Manu I don't think pull() will work. The input for it is pull(.data, var = -1) and my prof has the format set up as ____(____ = ____(____))

Comment: *"Smoking data is binary (yes/no) in a column that's titled as "SmokeNow""* So take a look at what `sum(SmokeNow == "yes")` does (assuming `SmokeNow` has string entries `"yes"` and `"no"`). Then all you need to do is consider (as in: divide by) the total number of people in your cohort.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I get this error when I try running the sum(SmokeNow == 'Yes')    Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Comment: You need to edit your post to include sample data in a reproducible way (e.g. using `dput`). Otherwise this will continue to be a guessing game, and we won't be able to help.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I updated it to include more of the assignment. I'm not sure if this is what you're referring to or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. It seems that you should use `sample_n()` rather than `sample()`. To find the proportion in one line, you would use `mean()`.

```
sample_size <- 100

NHANES_adult %>%
  sample_n(sample_size) %>%  
  summarize(p_smok = mean(SmokeNow == "Yes")) %>% 
  pull(p_smok)
```